# Domino security so it won't prompt for log in on folder change

Tags: lotus-domino

Hello fellow yellow bleeders.

We have a portal database that is in the root folder and the portal has links that point to DBs that are in subsequent folders(\app, \dev ...).

What can be done so Domino won't ask for log in when the users that logged in the portal won't be prompted when they open links in other folders.

Thank you

Comment: How are the users being authenticated initially?  Is the Domino Directory used for authentication?  Are you using the Domino IHS Apache server?  Are you using Internet Site documents?

Comment: Standard Domino Directory authentication, but may go to session based if solution is easier

Comment: Session based authentication works, and is easy to implement in the Server doc or Internet Site doc depending on which is used.

Comment: Without session authentication, you would have to deal with realm documents. It has probably been at least ten years since the last time I thought about them. Without them, the realm defaults to the second-to-last part of the URL that caused authentication, so even though your portal database is at root, you may have authenticated in a view realm and therefore would have to reauthenticate to access any other database, even in root.  Realm documents fix this.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_WEB_SITE_AUTHENTICATION_REALM_STEPS.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single server or multi-server HTTP session authentication will work for the entire domain.

In the Server document or the Internet Site document:

[image]